# invalid WAMP message: missing array close or invalid additional args

Tags: java, android

> D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnReader: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection: reader created and started
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: running
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnWriter: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection: writer created and started
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnReader: invalid WAMP message: missing
>   array close or invalid additional args
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: opening handshake received
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection: WAMP session
>   163056330058b5c9094c0d3240526863 established
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: WebSockets Close received
>   (1007 - null) D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: run() :
>   ConnectionLost D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: ended
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: fail connection [code = 3,
>   reason = WebSockets connection lost
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: quit
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: ended D/MAIN_ACT__CHAT_CLOSE:
>   WebSockets connection lost D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection:
>   worker threads stopped

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final AutobahnConnection autobahnConnection = new AutobahnConnection();

    private static class WebSocketPubSubEvent {
        public int num;
        public String name;
        public boolean flag;
        public Date created;
        public double rand;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autobahnConnection.connect("ws://95.213.194.229:9000", new Autobahn.SessionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
                autobahnConnection.subscribe("chat/topic",
                        WebSocketPubSubEvent.class,
                        new Autobahn.EventHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onEvent(String topic, Object event) {
                                WebSocketPubSubEvent evt = (WebSocketPubSubEvent) event;
                                Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITI__CHAT", evt.name);
                                Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITI__CHAT", new Integer(evt.num).toString());
                                Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITI__CHAT", evt.flag ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
                                Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITI__CHAT", new Integer(evt.created.getHours()).toString());
                                Log.d("MAIN_ACTIVITI__CHAT", new Double(evt.rand).toString());
                            }
                        }
                );

                autobahnConnection.sendTextMessage("Hello from DANIEL!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s) {
                Log.d("MAIN_ACT__CHAT_CLOSE", s);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If remove `autobahnConnection.sendTextMessage("Hello from DANIEL!!!");` it worked OK and connection didn't lost:

> D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnReader: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection: reader created and started
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader: running
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnWriter: created
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection: writer created and started
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnReader: invalid WAMP message: missing
>   array close or invalid additional args
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: opening handshake received
>   D/de.tavendo.autobahn.AutobahnConnection: WAMP session
>   212228657158b64424d3300506265704 established

But if I send string message from javascript client it worked ok too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending message to websocket server write it after subscribe process:

```
autobahnConnection.publish("chat/topic", new Object() {
    final String msg = "Message for you, ... <3";
});
```